# Linq and lambda function in List of custom objects

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I used to retrieve the number of items that I've skipped before reaching a certain condition this way:

```
List<double> series1X = new List<double> {4,6,8,9,10 };
List<double> series1Y = new List<double> { 10, 20, 15, 70,5 };
List<double> series2X = new List<double> { 1,2,3,6,7,8.1,8.2,8.3,8.4,9,9.75};

int j=0;
j = series2X.TakeWhile(p => p < series1X[0]).Count();
```

So j is the index of the item of series2X that is the next to the first item of series1X.

Now I'm rewriting this to `DataPoint`  that has X, Y properties. I've tried to do the same but I can't access that X or Y.

In this case

```
List<DataPoint> series1 = new  List<DataPoint>();
List<DataPoint> series2 = new  List<DataPoint>();
```

How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: Please show your attempt at the solution for using a list of `DataPoint` objects along with the errors or other problems it has.  Is it generating wrong output, not compiling, or what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your question but I think you're looking for something like;

```
j = series2X.TakeWhile(p => p.X < series1[0].X && p.Y < series1[0].Y).Count();'
```

In LINQ to Objects you access properties like you would anywhere else in C#, with dot notation. `p` is the current item in `series2` which is of type `DataPoint` and so is every item in `series1` so you can just do `p.MyProperty` for any property on any type.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that a little after, I was trying to do that to the frist "p". BTW, in my question I tried to type "DataPoint" between "<--->" and some of the information was missing. Didn't know that feature of SO.